# Project Euler #453 confusion

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, project-euler

So I decided to give a shot on the #453 project euler problem but there is something that confuses me with the numbers given. I decided to start by calculating the possible arrangements of 4 vertices in the 9 vertex grid. To do that I used the binomial coefficient which gives (for the first example) 126 different arrangements. I then removed all non valid arrangements (polygons with straight lines) but the result is smaller than what described. I am probably doing something wrong and I can't figure out what is the issue. Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: 
[Here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=453) is the link

Comment: A link to or description of the problem would be helpfull.

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  are missing the fact that some arrangements of four vertices can produce more than one polygon. Eg {(0,0), (0,2), (1,1) ,(1,2)}

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Now I wonder if I'm going the right way about this.

Comment: @Veritas That's much more difficult to say :-)